# How to store session in the browser?

Tags: java, angular, playframework

I'm using `play framework 2.8.x` for backend and `angular 8` for frontend. I need to store some data in the session on the server-side but I couldn't do it because of backend and frontend works on the different ports, the backend is `localhost:9000` and frontend are `localhost:4200` and my session not stores in the browser. 
that is my controller on the backend:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    public Result verifyToken(Http.Request request) {
        return ok(userInfo).addingToSession(request, "sessionData", "test");
    }
}
```

This is my frontend:

```
export class HttpService {
    sendRequestToBackend(tokenValue: String): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>(((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = "localhost:9000/user/verifyToken";
      const tokenRequest = { token: tokenValue };
      let body = JSON.stringify(tokenRequest);
      let options = this.getHttpOptions();
      this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            resolve(true);
          }, error => reject(error)
        );
    }));
  }
}
```

When the server sent response to the client in the response object I saw the cookie from the server side but this one not saved on the browser cookie.
[image: Response headers from the server]

How can I solve this issue? How can I save cookie from the `localhost:9000` in the `localhost:4200`?

Comment: You can start proxy as a part of Angular dev server, so in this case cookies which came from Play app will be stored in browser cookie. Or another option - it seems like session cookie stored with same site policy, then they should be turned off for development purpose only. For prod setup any cookie should be for same site.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko thanks for the help! Can you give some examples or where I can read about it?

Comment: Please, take a look at: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsSession. You can try and set `session.sameSite = "lax"` in `application.conf`. Let me know whether it helps or not .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After receiving response from below url

> localhost:9000/user/verifyToken

You can use `localstorage`

You can use DOM element.

as follows

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using Storage.setItem().

1. localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
2. var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
3. localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
4. localStorage.clear();

Comment: what do you mean? You advise to me save cookie into local storage? But how can I get this data on the server-side?

Comment: @John Actually you have to handle it in client side after receiving response from API request you can store the response in **localStorage**

Comment: no, I need to handle it in the server-side. For instance, I need to serve by admin panel and I send the request to the server and server have to check me and if I don't have access to this page the server must reject my request.